# Microsoft Access database primary key

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Not me so I might not do the question justice; however, my suite mate was working on a database in Microsoft Access 2013 and somehow deleted the primary key.  He didn't notice until after saving his progress.  Is there a way to revert this, or is he going to have to do it again from the ground up?

Comment: You don't mention if the table had an implicit relationship to other tables, so you can have one of two scenarios: (1) Table not related to any other tables; or (2) there was a relationship (did he get a warning on the delete?) Did he delete the field from the table or just delete the index? If he deleted the field, what type of values were in the field? If an AutoNumber, and not related, then no big deal. If something like a part#, where can you recover from? Need more specifics to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to revert it back (undo the deletion of a field).
If the field was part of a Relationship JOIN to another field in another table, or the field was part of a JOIN to another field in Queries, then your database is now potentially seriously broken.
If the field was not part of any JOIN anywhere, then the database should still work without it, although queries may execute slower because an indexed field has vanished.
If the field was Autonumber, recreating it from scratch *might* work, if it had no skipped (deleted) records, that is, the order was perfectly sequential.